# Как убрать цифры и символы в URL сайта (Перенаправление URL)?

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect

Например есть форма контактной связи доступная по адрессу - mysite.ru/contact
Я могу добавить цифры (mysite.ru/contact/123) или символы (mysite.ru/contact-/) или написать с большой буквы (mysite.ru/CONTACT) сайт все равно будет показывать данную страницу но с этими URL.
Можно как-то перенаправлять все эти URL на стандартный (mysite.ru/contact).
Сайт работает на WordPress.

Comment: 301 редирект не подойдёт?

Comment: Как это реализовать?

Comment: Плагином https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/